# Offsetting categorised symbology for features overlapping (only when features are overlapping)

Tags: qgis, symbology, offset

I'm trying to look for a solution to a problem I am having with a polygon layer in QGIS.

I've produced a 'Boundary' layer in QGIS, such boundaries are leveled the lower levels are inside the higher levels (for lack of a better explanation, I've attached an image below).

Level 1 = Red;
Level 2 = Orange;
Level 3 = Green;
Level 4 = Yellow

[image]

When I am drawing these polygons, I snap them to the vertices and unfortunately this prevents me from seeing the full picture / extent of the symbology, example image below.

[image]

From the image, all 4 levels share the same two vertices (the top two) but you cannot see all four symbols, only Level 1.

I have tried offsetting the symbology manually within symbology styling (i.e. +0.25, 0, -0.25, -0.5), but this means that the symbology will be offset even when the polygons are not sharing vertices, which i do not want.

This is a very poor and drawn example of what I'm looking for.

[image]

Hoping someone who has had this problem previously has a solution for this problem, any help would be much appreicated.

Comment: Why is offsetting undesirable? It is a simple, straightforward solution to your issue. You also could use strokes instead of solid lines. Furthermore, since you know your polygons share a border, why not simple let them overlap? E.g. municipality and parcels borders overlay, and it is common practice to display the "greater" border on top.

Comment: @Erik When I eventually print this project as a PDF I need them to show. Plus I need a solution for other layers, some with line features that overlap and if they're not shown in their exact planned position (not offset) this can cause issues in my line of work.

Comment: You could convert your polygons to lines, split those at the vertices and then create a conditional offset using data defined override.

Comment: I find it useful to have different line width and control the feature rendering order to put the thinner lines on top

Comment: @JGH hmm that's a good idea, I'll give that a go. Thank you.